# Angular 2 - Invoking function from a JS file (chart.js) - function not found

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I am using the chart.js library and the ng2-charts angular 2 directives in my project and everything works fine except I am having trouble calling functions directly from the chart.js library. In particular, I am trying to invoke the getElementsAtEvent function and I am getting the "... is not a function" error. I know the chart.js library is loading, because the charts are rendering and I know the function is in the library because I can search for it and find it.

What I have now is:

- `systemjs.config.js` with a map:
  `'chartjs': '../../areas/dashboard/plugins/chart.js/dist/'` and packages: `'chartjs': {main: 'Chart.bundle.min.js', defaultExtensions: 'js'}` among other things of course
- `app.component.ts` with `import 'chartjs';
  declare let Chart;`

Then I have:

```
var chartEl = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("chart_2").childNodes[1];
var ctx = chartEl.getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(e);
```

and I get an error message that "getElementsAtEvent is not a function". I know it runs up until that point because I went through the debugger.
 It is my understanding that the function should be available to me. Is there something else I need to do to be able to reference/invoke the function from the js library?

Thank you very much

Comment: Aren't you supposed to specify a chart configuration?

Comment: I am not sure. Do you know how to do that in the newest version of chart.js? Would leaving that our lead to the "... Not a function error"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever may be interested - I ended up digesting the chart.js code and writing some custom functions within my Angular 2 files to take the event and extract the data (by detecting the mouse position and seeing what items were clicked on, etc).

If anyone needs any help or insight, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide

Answer (score 0):

This is probably another issue, but where is e coming from? It's weird for the myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(e) call to be floating around without being inside some sort of callback like

```
myChart.onclick = function(e){
        var points = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(e)
}
```

Also is your new Chart definitely a chart.js Chart object and not something else? I've never used ng2-charts but does it provide it's own Chart object that's missing this method?

Comment: It's in a function `public chartClicked(e: any): void {};` which is called in the angular 2 code with `(chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"`